# jupyter notebook and ipython don't take correct path after activating a conda environment

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, ipython, virtual-environment

I have setup **anaconda3** for multiple users in a lab workstation at `/opt/anaconda3` so that other users don't have to set up a fresh anaconda3 install for themselves.

Then I created an environment called `zud` for my use. So currently, the workstation has two environments as listed below.

```
(base) zuddler@silp252-dl360:~$ conda env list
# conda environments:
#
zud                      /home/zuddler/.conda/envs/zud
base                  *  /opt/anaconda3
```

When I am activating my environment using `conda activate zud`, jupyter and ipython are not taking the correct path and thus I am not able to use manually installed libraries in my environment, so for an example, in my environment `zud` I installed `python-igraph` using `conda install -c conda-forge python-igraph` but cannot access it though jupyter notebook or ipython; they give `ModuleNotFoundError`.

Please go through the results of `which` commands on `base` and `zud` environments below.

For `base`:

```
(base) zuddler@silp252-dl360:~$ which python
/opt/anaconda3/bin/python
(base) zuddler@silp252-dl360:~$ which jupyter
/opt/anaconda3/bin/jupyter
(base) zuddler@silp252-dl360:~$ which ipython
/opt/anaconda3/bin/ipython
(base) zuddler@silp252-dl360:~$ which conda
/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda
```

and for `zud`:

```
(zud) zuddler@silp252-dl360:~$ which python
/home/zuddler/.conda/envs/zud/bin/python
(zud) zuddler@silp252-dl360:~$ which jupyter
/opt/anaconda3/bin/jupyter
(zud) zuddler@silp252-dl360:~$ which ipython
/opt/anaconda3/bin/ipython
(zud) zuddler@silp252-dl360:~$ which conda
/opt/anaconda3/condabin/conda
```

from the above results, I assume that upon activating `zud`, jupyter notebook and ipython are not taking the correct path.

*Please suggest what's going on here and how to fix it.*

In case any further details are needed, please let me know as well so that I can update my question accordingly.

Further, if my problem is answered somewhere, please let me know the link as I was not able to find its solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I observed the issue here! On changing the conda environment from `base` to `zud`, the *ipython* and *jupyter* utilities are still being used of the `base` env.

The main reason behind could be - In the `zud` env ipython and jupyter are not installed. Due to which, both are accessed from the `base` env. Try installing them in `zud` and see if the problem is fixed.

Comment: Ok. I tried installing `ipython` and `juptyer` in my environment and it worked, they are taking correct path now. Thanks.